# My code requests exception to be thrown, but when I do, it says it should not be thrown

Tags: java, exception, overriding

I get this error when compiling my program:

```
./GUI/mainWindow.java:30: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown 
            clientUI.initClientUI(); 
                             ^ 
1 error
```

But my method actually throws Exception:

```
public final void initClientUI() throws Exception {
```

However, if I remove the "throws Exception" part, try to compile, then add it again, the program compiles successfully. Can anyone explain why is this happening?

**EDIT**:
If I add "throws Exception" to the method I am calling

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) throws Exception { //<-----add Exception there
            ClientWindow clientUI = new ClientWindow();
            clientUI.initClientUI();
```

I get this error:

```
./GUI/mainWindow.java:28: error: actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in <anonymous GUI.mainWindow$1> cannot implement actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) throws Exception {
                    ^
  overridden method does not throw Exception
1 error
```

Comment: As for the last problem (in the EDIT) the compiler says it all: "overridden method does not throw Exception". I.e. if you override some method, the **method signature of the overridden method must not be changed**.

Answer (score 2):

By saying

```
public final void initClientUI() throws Exception {
```

you are telling the compiler that `initClientUI()` is allowed to throw `Exception` or any subclass of `Exception`. Since `Exception` is checked, any method that calls `initClientUI()` must either catch `Exception` or have it listed in its `throws` clause.

I'd recommend reading the [tutorial on exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the declaration of your method, your problem is when you call it. When you declare a method like this

```
public final void initClientUI() throws Exception
```

your compiler will know that it will throw an exception. That's good, no problem so far. But when you call it, you have to deal with this exception.

So when you say

```
client.initClientUI()
```

your compiler says "this method throws an exception, pleas handle it". Now you have two options:

```
try {
    client.initClientUI()
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

or declare your method that calls `client.initClientUI()` also with `throws Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

`throws Exception` means you are throwing it to the calling method,And Calling method should be responsible of handeling that `exception` either by throwing it again or catching it with `try catch`.

You should do it this way

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
            try{
              ClientWindow clientUI = new ClientWindow();
              clientUI.initClientUI();
            }catch(Exception e){
              // handle exception
            }
```